# Can you index elements of an array in Postgres?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm wondering if I can do something like

```
CREATE INDEX firstelement ON mytable (myarray[1]);
```

this particular syntax creates a syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, with extra parentesis:

```
CREATE INDEX firstelement ON mytable ((myarray[1]));
```